# Data not saved in SQL Server database after rerun c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I've finally got my connection string working. Now I have written some code to insert into a table called `Customers` in the `Database.mdf`. When I click the "registreer" button in the form I insert the name in the usernameTF2 into the table and after that I call the `ShowCustomers` method to reload the listbox..

When I rerun the program, it still shows the previous made names in the listbox, but still doesn't show the names in the server explorer.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ProductClient.ProductService;
using TestDB;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ProductServiceClient productProxy = new ProductServiceClient();

        SqlConnection connection; 
        string connectionString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            ShowCustomers();
        }

        private void ShowCustomers()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer", connection))
            {
                DataTable productTable2 = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(productTable2);

                lstBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
                lstBox.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstBox.DataSource = productTable2;
            }
        }

        private void registreerBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string response = productProxy.Register(usernameTF2.Text);
            wachtwoordLAB.Text = response;

            string query = "INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(@Name, 20)"; ////

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))////
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))////
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",usernameTF2.Text);////
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Added");
                connection.Close();
            }

            ShowCustomers();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The `Copy to Output Directory` is already set to `Copy if newer`.

Connectionstring:

In the form:

```
connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

In the app config:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: You need to tell us what your connection string is; obfusticate your password if you have one.

Comment: Did you refresh the server explorer?

Comment: In the form:    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


In the app config:      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Yes i did refresh all.

Comment: Your connection string assignment may be referencing another connection string in you app config.  I see a reference to a named connection string called "TestDB.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString" and the one you're showing in the app config doesn't have a name property.  Is that just that the app config snippet only has part of the contents?

Comment: I made a reference to a project called TestDB which has the Database.mdf in it .. It gave me  nullreference errors when I  tried to open the form from testDB project into the LoginProject form. So i put the same app config connectionString in the app.config in the LoginProject. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that with Server Explorer, you are looking at the same `Database.mdf` file that your program is using? If you are not 100% sure, replace `|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf` in your connection string with the absolute file path of the database file you've connected to in Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe after looking at the inside code that it should be placing correctly, I am surprised that you are not getting an error while trying to connect to the database though because I feel it is a connection problem. Without looking at the connection properties it is hard to tell of course.

What I would suggest is putting the code in surrounding try catch statements in order to see what is exactly going wrong on connection or input if that is the case. Along side with this you can also check your event viewer in windows to say why connection was not established I believe.

I Really do hope this helps.

For further information on connection strings I believe a great website to use is www.connectionstrings.com to double check. If you still have problems feel free to post more information so we can help you more.